# Word for the range between two ends of a spectrum

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I’m looking for a word to fill the gap in the sentence:

> An exploration of the mechanical–organic _______.

or

> An exploration of the ____ between the mechanical and the organic.

The context is typeface design.

Some loose associations: *balance, spectrum, dynamic, dialogue, dispute, dialectic, axis, equilibrium, dichotomy, gamut, space, range*.

[Edited for brevity and clarity. I would delete the question but cannot due to the activity. Please refrain from further downvoting and depriving me of Fake Internet Points.]

Comment: I think "gamut" can be used when you're exploring esthetic choices over a range.

Comment: *...a dialog between the mechanical and the organic...*

Comment: Interaction, perhaps.  But what is organic about a type face?

Comment: Continuum? I find the question confusing, as it seems to be asking for one thing, yet your suggestions don't fit the idea of *finding balance.*

Comment: @GArthurBrown Continuum is fine! Sorry about the question, I tried not to be too suggestive in the title because I was not sure what I was looking for (the more elusive and abstract the word, the better). I might just ask another question on how this one should be titled!

Comment: @Xanne Subtle irregularities or glyph construction mimicking handwritten or handdrawn patterns.

Comment: Could you give a little more information about the mechanical and organic attributes of typeface design that you are exploring.  It might help!

Comment: Mechanical: squarish ovals (superellipses, or “squircles”), flat arms on letters f, t, horizontal middle stroke of letter a. Some organic treats: flared stroke terminals, curved top-right of letters c, e. The word(s) I’m interested in could be well applied to other terms, e.g. humanist–geometric (which is kind of similar to the organic–mechanical dilemma). There are some more typically used terms like grotesk, neogrotesk, transitional, oldstyle, if you want to explore but I don’t think they are held in opposition, they’re historical terms, so they’re more commonly listed in sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with continuum, as suggested in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

When two contradictory approaches seem to offer equally valid explanations to a phenomenon, the two approaches can be said to be held **in tension**.

The closest definition I've found in a dictionary is the following:

> *tension* [noun]...
>
> - c: a balance maintained in an artistic work between opposing forces or elements

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tension)]

The *doctrine of tensions* is a well-known feature of at least many hermeneutical schools (eg the Bible teaches both predestination and free will). In the physical world, the wave-particle duality of radiant light etc is another illustration.

Answer (score 1):

**sweet spot**

> An ideal or most favorable location, level, area, or combination of
> factors for a particular activity or purpose
>
> *The winery in Rutherford, best known for its loamy Cabernet Sauvignon, has a **sweet spot** of 8 acres for Chardonnay, which has
> produced spectacular wines.* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sweet%20spot)

> An optimum point or combination of factors or qualities.
>
> *Growth has settled into the 2 % to 3 % range that many experts consider the country's **sweet spot**.*[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/sweet_spot)

---

> These examples show that x-height follows the "Goldilocks
> principle"—the optimal x-height is neither too tall nor too short, but
> somewhere in between. Many typographic variables behave in this way;
> the "**sweet spot**" exist in the middle of the continuum. [Karen
> Cheng; *Designing Type*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Designing_Type/G5sJEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Sweet%20spot%22%20%20typeface&pg=PA38&printsec=frontcover)

> *Leading* is the amount of vertical space between lines. As with measure, if you have too little or too much leading, the text becomes hard to read. The **sweet spot** for leading tends to be 120%—145% of the font size.
> [Yevgeniy Brikman; *Hello, Startup*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hello_Startup/VunJCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Sweet%20spot%22%20%20typeface&pg=PA109&printsec=frontcover)